# Doxygen: exclude file/directory NOT containing word

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

In Doxyfile I can exclude specific files or directories in the **EXCLUDE** option or by wildcard pattern in **EXCLUDE_PATTERNS**.

How can I exclude directories which not contain a pattern? Like this:

    `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = */!(dirname1-*)/*`

The other way would be to have an option like **INCLUDE_PATTERNS**, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Maybe you can do something with FILE_PATTERNS.

Comment: I tried, but seems it only works for filenames not for file paths.